# C++ - If statement inside loop not working properly

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement

I'm trying to use [`std::cin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) whilst having one option loop back to the start. The loop works perfectly but when I add in an extra option to one of the `if` statements then type that in, it doesn't think that what I chose is an option.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

int main() {  
    string  choice;
    char restart;

    do {
        choice.clear();
        cout << "Which do you take? " << endl;
        cin >> choice;

        if (choice == "all") {
            //cout code
            restart = 'y';
        }
        else if (choice == "dagger" || choice == "the dagger") {
            choice.clear();
            cout << "You pick up the dagger" << endl << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            choice.clear();
            cout << "That isn't an option, pick again... "<< endl << endl;
            sleep_for(1s);
            restart = 'y';
        }

    } while (restart == 'y');
}
```

When I type in *"dagger"*, it works just fine, but when I type in *" the dagger"* it says runs the `else` code, then loops back to *"Which do you take"* and then chooses *"dagger"* instantly.

Comment: `cin >> choice` reads one word, so given the dagger, it reads the and leaves dagger in the stream for later.

Comment: The `>>` operator reads words, not lines. Use std::getline instead. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Comment: Debugging note: When you want to know what's up with an input, the first thing you should do is print out the input. Kills most bugs dead instantly.

Comment: Thank you both so much! I didnt know that about cin.

Comment: @user4581301 — `choice` is `std::string`, not a stream. `choice.clear();` is correct.

Comment: Thank you. I have no idea how I jumped to that conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `std::cin` with the `>>` operator. This operator reads formatted input (words) instead of unformatted input (lines). Rather than reading `"the dagger"`, your program is simply reading `"the"`, and leaving `"dagger"` in the input buffer for later.

To read unformatted input to `choice`, use `std::getline(std::cin, choice);` instead.